# RxJava: How can I use distinct() operator on the whole sequence of values and then merge it with another observable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Please look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE39H.png) beforehand.
Imagine I've got the following methods:

```
Observable<FootballPlayer> loadPlayersForTeam(int teamId)
```

for example, Barcelona FC has a `teamId = 13213`, so `loadPlayersForTeam(13213)` will return an Observable that emits FootballPlayers objects:
`FootballPlayer("Messi", 10), FootballPlayer("Suarez", 9), etc`.

This observable will eventually emit every football player of the **current** squad of Barcelona FC. *This corresponds to the regions **#1 + #2** at the picture.*

And then I've got another methods:

```
Observable<Coach> loadCoachesForTeam(int teamId)
Single<FootballPlayer> loadPlayer(int playerId)
```

I hope the names of the object speak for themselves. And here's the thing: there's favoritePlayerId field under class Coach, so effectively every Coach maps to some playerId. For example, Coach('Pep Guardiola') will have .favoritePlayerId = 9 which stands for Messi (note that we could have downloaded FootballPlayer("Messi", 10) from Observable loadPlayersForTeam(int teamId).

And it may happen that `Coach('Ronald Koeman').favoritePlayerId = 99` and there's no `FootballPlayer` with `.favoritePlayerId = 99` under current squad of Barcelona FC (so we won't get it using `loadPlayersForTeam()`) and because we're really huge supporters and we have to use `loadPlayer(99)` to get that old `FootballPlayer`. A region of players that we can download using `loadCoachesForTeam()` and then calling loadPlayer() for each emitted coach is region #3.

**Here's a question**:
FootballPlayer objects are really heavy, that's why we don't want to call loadPlayerSingle(int playerId) for region #2 and only to call for region #3, for example: we don't want to call `loadPlayer(9)` – load Messi using this method, cause we've already received him in the observable from loadPlayersForTeam().

*What I want is to return a new `Observable<FootballPlayer>` – it should emit both current + favorites of the coaches (note: FootballPlayers themselves and not their Ids only) and only call loadPlayer() for the Ids which are not in the current squad, cause these calls are really expensive*: if my `playerIds` from FootballPlayer objects from `loadPlayersForATeam` are `9, 10, 21, 1` and the .favoritePlayerId of `loadCoachesForTeam()` are `1, 3, 44, 5, 1` I want to make sure I won't call `loadPlayer(1)`: again, because we can get it from the 1st observable (which is `loadPlayersForTeam(Barcelona.teamId)`). The ids in the 1st observable is unique, and you can't say so about the 2nd one (loadCoachesForTeam(Barcelona.teamId). So what I tried is to use `distinct()` and `mergeWith()` for this 2 observables. But `distinct()` only operates on the prefix of the events so far and doesn't wait for the observable to comlpete: it may happen that we get 1 from the 2nd observable.

How can I call distinct for the whole Observable and then add there some more values without using Subjects (call `loadPlayer()` for region #3 only and take FootballPlayers from #2 from the 1st observable)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't solve this without Subjects. You can use [this subject caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545490/61158) mechanism and do some `flatMapping` with it.

Comment: OK, could you give me a high level template for solving this problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this subject caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545490/61158) mechanism and do some flatMapping with it. On a high level, I'd do the following:

```
RxCache<Integer, Observable<FootballPlayer>> cache = 
    new RxCache<>(id -> loadPlayer(id).toObservable());

Observable<Integer> teamIds = ...

teamIds
.flatMap(team -> 
    Observable.concat(
       loadPlayersForTeam(team)
           doOnNext(player -> cache.putIfAbsent(player.id, player))
       ,
       loadCoachesForTeam(team)
           .flatMap(coach -> cache.get(coach.favoritePlayerId)),
)
.subscribe(player -> { /* ... */ });
```

Where RxCache is:

```
public class RxCache<K, V> {

    final ConcurrentHashMap<K, AsyncSubject<V>> cache;
    final Func1<K, Observable<V>> valueGenerator;

    public RxCache(Func1<K, Observable<V>> valueGenerator) {
        this.valueGenerator = valueGenerator;
        this.cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public Observable<V> get(K key) {
        AsyncSubject<V> o = cache.get(key);
        if (o != null) {
            return o;
        }
        o = AsyncSubject.create();
        AsyncSubject<V> p = cache.putIfAbsent(key, o);
        if (p != null) {
            return p;
        }
        valueGenerator.call(key).subscribe(o);
        return o;
    }

    public void putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        if (!cache.contains(key)) {
            AsyncSubject<V> subj = AsyncSubject.create();
            subj.onNext(value);
            subj.onCompleted();
            cache.putIfAbsent(key, subj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but it's not right in the logical way: I want to call loadPlayersForTeam() for each team first (main thing) and then merge it with loadCoachesForTeam(team) -> coach.favoritePlayerId (we don't have coach.favPlayer as a FootballPlayer, it's playerId). And if there's no such id (player with such id in loadPlayersForTeam() to be precise) then we'll call loadPlayer(playerId) cause we want to output the stream of players. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Updated the answer.